# HTML structure?

Tags: html

I think this one is simple just explain it a bit please...

Supose I have this index.php (**Don't look for script errors**)

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
require(home.php)
</body>
</html>
```

And my home.php (I saw this somewhere and I am wondering, even if it is working is it wrong?)
Instead of having again the normal html structure as above, you have:

```
<body>
some code
</body>
```

LEAVING OUT all the other tags.

Is this correct? Yes? No? Why?

Thank you

Edit: What if I am calling a js script in my head tag? Would the home.php inherite it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably shouldn't have the `<body>` tag again, but otherwise okay.

Comment: +1, all that matters is the HTML that gets sent to the client, individual PHP files don't have to be valid HTML provided they combine to produce valid HTML

Answer (score 2):

It is incorrect. For every version of HTML, the body element may only be a child of the html element. It may never be a child of another body element.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not correct, there are quite a bit of errors, but it won't work because of the following reasons:

1. You don't open/close PHP using the `<?php` and `?>` tags. This way require() just won't execute;
2. Require() needs quotes (since it's argument should be a string), so `require('home.php');` is correct;
3. As I already changed in point 2: you have to end every argument with a semicolon (;);
4. You should probably replace the `<body></body>` tags in home.php with `<?php ?>` tags, so that Google can't index that page (and can only do it from index.php;

Apart from that you also have these markup errors:

1. Always use a Doctype. Otherwise your HTML won't validate;
2. The `<title></title>` tag is mandatory;

Hope this helps.

Comment: As for the script writting errors I pointed out in my question **Don't look for script errors** :) Ok... I see both options... Yes and No.. :) And as I unterstood it is fine not to include all tags, and is better to always use the <title>???

Comment: @Pavlos1316: It's fine not to include all tags in that it will work in all browsers, but officially you should always have a doctype and a title. It's in the specification and it's considered good practice to include it, otherwise your page won't validate.

Comment: So html, title and is ok... what about my other question I edited 3-4 minutes ago??? Will the home.php inherite js scripts that are called in index.php???

Comment: Yes, definitely. I propose you read about about what Javascript and PHP exactly are: a client-side and a server-side language. The user doesn't know you use php, he just gets some data back. He doesn't mind how the server assembled that data, so everything he receives is parsed. You have to think of the require() function as a way to "include" another script (which is also the reason you can use the include() function instead with some small differences).

Bottom line: you can include anything in index.php. Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You are including the file, so php is litterally "putting it in between there".

BTW: you now have double body tags.

Answer (score 0):

Re-iterating what others are saying. It would look and behave the same (most likely), but fails semantically.

That is all.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the  start and end tag in home.php and it'll be ok (check http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php for more information if needed)

Answer (score 0):

Let's main page to provide other pages by `<BODY>` tag